# Django Rest Framework - ListCreateAPIView Prints Nothing

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have create a API for list and create using django rest framework. But it is not printing anything in Web browsable api. I don't what is the problem. When i am printing `queryset` and `serializer` variable it is giving proper output as `QuerySet`. Why this is happening?

Views.py

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import MovieSerializer
from movie.models import Movie
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

   class MovieList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
       queryset = Movie.objects.all()[:10]
       serializer_class = MovieSerializer
       permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

       def list(self, request):
           # Note the use of `get_queryset()` instead of `self.queryset`
           queryset = self.get_queryset()
           # print(queryset)
           serializer = MovieSerializer(queryset, many=True)
           # print(serializer.data)
           return Response(serializer.data)
```

Serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from movie.models import Movie

   class MovieSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
       class Meta:
           model = Movie
           fields = [
               'popularity',
               'director',
               'genre',
               'imdb_score',
               'name',
           ]
```

See the image for reference.
[image]

Comment: is your data populated?

Comment: yes it is populated

Comment: You're not using a `ModelSerializer` but just a `Serializer`.

Also, take care of slicing a queryset in that way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `serializers.py`. You have to use `ModelSerializer` instead `Serializer`.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from movie.models import Movie

   class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  # <- 
       class Meta:
           model = Movie
           fields = [
               'popularity',
               'director',
               'genre',
               'imdb_score',
               'name',
           ]
```